# how to get new lines by copying html as text in another div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

pls place cursor at the and of `lorem ipsum`
then hit Enter - new line
then write - `dolor`
result in `divb` is - `<div>lorem ipsum</div><div>dolor</div>`
how to get the following in `divb`:

```
<div>lorem ipsum</div>
<div>dolor</div>
```

```js
$('#diva').on('input', function(){
  let a = $(this).html();
  $('#divb').text(a);
});
```

```css
#diva, #divb{background:#ddd; padding:9px;}
#divb{white-space:pre-wrap;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='diva' contenteditable>
<div>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id='divb'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each line in a contenteditable is wrapped in a `div`.

You can split the HTML by a closing `div` tag, then join back with a newline:

```js
$('#diva').on('input', function() {
  let a = $(this).html();
  $('#divb').text(a.split("</div>").join("</div>\n"));
});
```

```css
#diva,
#divb {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 9px;
}

#divb {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='diva' contenteditable><div>lorem ipsum</div></div>
<br>
<div id='divb'></div>
```